# How to tell if an audio track follows A440 standard?

Tags: pitch, standard

I have a question about the A440 standard (A = 440 Hz) - does it really affect every single modern soundtrack?

How can I tell if an audio track has been made using the A440 Standard / 440Hz (as opposed to e.g. A = 432Hz)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 100% certain way to determine which equal-tempered scale standard was used as tuning basis for a song. However the vast majority is A440. Many electronic instruments don't really give you any choice.

However you ask how to determine it. You'll need to do a spectrum analysis and sum up the energy around the fundamental frequencies of the scales. The largest sum indicates that the given scale was used.

Below is a chart of frequencies in Hertz (Hz) for equal-tempered scale standards A432, A434, A436, A438, A440, A442, A444, A446:

```
┌───────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│   Note    │  A432   │  A434   │  A436   │  A438   │  A440   │  A442   │  A444   │  A446   │
├───────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┼─────────┤
│ C0        │   16.05 │   16.13 │   16.20 │   16.28 │   16.35 │   16.43 │   16.50 │   16.57 │
│  C#0/Db0  │   17.01 │   17.09 │   17.17 │   17.25 │   17.32 │   17.40 │   17.48 │   17.56 │
│ D0        │   18.02 │   18.10 │   18.19 │   18.27 │   18.35 │   18.44 │   18.52 │   18.60 │
│  D#0/Eb0  │   19.09 │   19.18 │   19.27 │   19.36 │   19.45 │   19.53 │   19.62 │   19.71 │
│ E0        │   20.23 │   20.32 │   20.41 │   20.51 │   20.60 │   20.70 │   20.79 │   20.88 │
│ F0        │   21.43 │   21.53 │   21.63 │   21.73 │   21.83 │   21.93 │   22.03 │   22.12 │
│  F#0/Gb0  │   22.70 │   22.81 │   22.91 │   23.02 │   23.12 │   23.23 │   23.33 │   23.44 │
│ G0        │   24.05 │   24.17 │   24.28 │   24.39 │   24.50 │   24.61 │   24.72 │   24.83 │
│  G#0/Ab0  │   25.48 │   25.60 │   25.72 │   25.84 │   25.96 │   26.07 │   26.19 │   26.31 │
│ A0        │   27.00 │   27.12 │   27.25 │   27.38 │   27.50 │   27.62 │   27.75 │   27.88 │
│  A#0/Bb0  │   28.61 │   28.74 │   28.87 │   29.00 │   29.14 │   29.27 │   29.40 │   29.53 │
│ B0        │   30.31 │   30.45 │   30.59 │   30.73 │   30.87 │   31.01 │   31.15 │   31.29 │
│ C1        │   32.11 │   32.26 │   32.41 │   32.55 │   32.70 │   32.85 │   33.00 │   33.15 │
│  C#1/Db1  │   34.02 │   34.18 │   34.33 │   34.49 │   34.65 │   34.81 │   34.96 │   35.12 │
│ D1        │   36.04 │   36.21 │   36.37 │   36.54 │   36.71 │   36.87 │   37.04 │   37.21 │
│  D#1/Eb1  │   38.18 │   38.36 │   38.54 │   38.71 │   38.89 │   39.07 │   39.24 │   39.42 │
│ E1        │   40.45 │   40.64 │   40.83 │   41.02 │   41.20 │   41.39 │   41.58 │   41.77 │
│ F1        │   42.86 │   43.06 │   43.26 │   43.46 │   43.65 │   43.85 │   44.05 │   44.25 │
│  F#1/Gb1  │   45.41 │   45.62 │   45.83 │   46.04 │   46.25 │   46.46 │   46.67 │   46.88 │
│ G1        │   48.11 │   48.33 │   48.55 │   48.78 │   49.00 │   49.22 │   49.44 │   49.67 │
│  G#1/Ab1  │   50.97 │   51.21 │   51.44 │   51.68 │   51.91 │   52.15 │   52.39 │   52.62 │
│ A1        │   54.00 │   54.25 │   54.50 │   54.75 │   55.00 │   55.25 │   55.50 │   55.75 │
│  A#1/Bb1  │   57.21 │   57.48 │   57.74 │   58.01 │   58.27 │   58.54 │   58.80 │   59.07 │
│ B1        │   60.61 │   60.89 │   61.17 │   61.45 │   61.74 │   62.02 │   62.30 │   62.58 │
│ C2        │   64.22 │   64.51 │   64.81 │   65.11 │   65.41 │   65.70 │   66.00 │   66.30 │
│  C#2/Db2  │   68.04 │   68.35 │   68.67 │   68.98 │   69.30 │   69.61 │   69.93 │   70.24 │
│ D2        │   72.08 │   72.42 │   72.75 │   73.08 │   73.42 │   73.75 │   74.08 │   74.42 │
│  D#2/Eb2  │   76.37 │   76.72 │   77.07 │   77.43 │   77.78 │   78.14 │   78.49 │   78.84 │
│ E2        │   80.91 │   81.28 │   81.66 │   82.03 │   82.41 │   82.78 │   83.16 │   83.53 │
│ F2        │   85.72 │   86.12 │   86.51 │   86.91 │   87.31 │   87.70 │   88.10 │   88.50 │
│  F#2/Gb2  │   90.82 │   91.24 │   91.66 │   92.08 │   92.50 │   92.92 │   93.34 │   93.76 │
│ G2        │   96.22 │   96.66 │   97.11 │   97.55 │   98.00 │   98.44 │   98.89 │   99.34 │
│  G#2/Ab2  │  101.94 │  102.41 │  102.88 │  103.35 │  103.83 │  104.30 │  104.77 │  105.24 │
│ A2        │  108.00 │  108.50 │  109.00 │  109.50 │  110.00 │  110.50 │  111.00 │  111.50 │
│  A#2/Bb2  │  114.42 │  114.95 │  115.48 │  116.01 │  116.54 │  117.07 │  117.60 │  118.13 │
│ B2        │  121.23 │  121.79 │  122.35 │  122.91 │  123.47 │  124.03 │  124.59 │  125.15 │
│ C3        │  128.43 │  129.03 │  129.62 │  130.22 │  130.81 │  131.41 │  132.00 │  132.60 │
│  C#3/Db3  │  136.07 │  136.70 │  137.33 │  137.96 │  138.59 │  139.22 │  139.85 │  140.48 │
│ D3        │  144.16 │  144.83 │  145.50 │  146.16 │  146.83 │  147.50 │  148.17 │  148.83 │
│  D#3/Eb3  │  152.74 │  153.44 │  154.15 │  154.86 │  155.56 │  156.27 │  156.98 │  157.68 │
│ E3        │  161.82 │  162.57 │  163.32 │  164.06 │  164.81 │  165.56 │  166.31 │  167.06 │
│ F3        │  171.44 │  172.23 │  173.03 │  173.82 │  174.61 │  175.41 │  176.20 │  177.00 │
│  F#3/Gb3  │  181.63 │  182.47 │  183.32 │  184.16 │  185.00 │  185.84 │  186.68 │  187.52 │
│ G3        │  192.43 │  193.32 │  194.22 │  195.11 │  196.00 │  196.89 │  197.78 │  198.67 │
│  G#3/Ab3  │  203.88 │  204.82 │  205.76 │  206.71 │  207.65 │  208.60 │  209.54 │  210.48 │
│ A3        │  216.00 │  217.00 │  218.00 │  219.00 │  220.00 │  221.00 │  222.00 │  223.00 │
│  A#3/Bb3  │  228.84 │  229.90 │  230.96 │  232.02 │  233.08 │  234.14 │  235.20 │  236.26 │
│ B3        │  242.45 │  243.57 │  244.70 │  245.82 │  246.94 │  248.06 │  249.19 │  250.31 │
│ C4        │  256.87 │  258.06 │  259.25 │  260.44 │  261.63 │  262.81 │  264.00 │  265.19 │
│  C#4/Db4  │  272.14 │  273.40 │  274.66 │  275.92 │  277.18 │  278.44 │  279.70 │  280.96 │
│ D4        │  288.33 │  289.66 │  290.99 │  292.33 │  293.66 │  295.00 │  296.33 │  297.67 │
│  D#4/Eb4  │  305.47 │  306.88 │  308.30 │  309.71 │  311.13 │  312.54 │  313.96 │  315.37 │
│ E4        │  323.63 │  325.13 │  326.63 │  328.13 │  329.63 │  331.13 │  332.62 │  334.12 │
│ F4        │  342.88 │  344.47 │  346.05 │  347.64 │  349.23 │  350.82 │  352.40 │  353.99 │
│  F#4/Gb4  │  363.27 │  364.95 │  366.63 │  368.31 │  369.99 │  371.68 │  373.36 │  375.04 │
│ G4        │  384.87 │  386.65 │  388.43 │  390.21 │  392.00 │  393.78 │  395.56 │  397.34 │
│  G#4/Ab4  │  407.75 │  409.64 │  411.53 │  413.42 │  415.30 │  417.19 │  419.08 │  420.97 │
│ A4        │  432.00 │  434.00 │  436.00 │  438.00 │  440.00 │  442.00 │  444.00 │  446.00 │
│  A#4/Bb4  │  457.69 │  459.81 │  461.93 │  464.04 │  466.16 │  468.28 │  470.40 │  472.52 │
│ B4        │  484.90 │  487.15 │  489.39 │  491.64 │  493.88 │  496.13 │  498.37 │  500.62 │
│ C5        │  513.74 │  516.12 │  518.49 │  520.87 │  523.25 │  525.63 │  528.01 │  530.39 │
│  C#5/Db5  │  544.29 │  546.81 │  549.33 │  551.85 │  554.37 │  556.88 │  559.40 │  561.92 │
│ D5        │  576.65 │  579.32 │  581.99 │  584.66 │  587.33 │  590.00 │  592.67 │  595.34 │
│  D#5/Eb5  │  610.94 │  613.77 │  616.60 │  619.43 │  622.25 │  625.08 │  627.91 │  630.74 │
│ E5        │  647.27 │  650.27 │  653.26 │  656.26 │  659.25 │  662.25 │  665.25 │  668.24 │
│ F5        │  685.76 │  688.93 │  692.11 │  695.28 │  698.46 │  701.63 │  704.81 │  707.98 │
│  F#5/Gb5  │  726.53 │  729.90 │  733.26 │  736.63 │  739.99 │  743.35 │  746.72 │  750.08 │
│ G5        │  769.74 │  773.30 │  776.86 │  780.43 │  783.99 │  787.55 │  791.12 │  794.68 │
│  G#5/Ab5  │  815.51 │  819.28 │  823.06 │  826.83 │  830.61 │  834.38 │  838.16 │  841.94 │
│ A5        │  864.00 │  868.00 │  872.00 │  876.00 │  880.00 │  884.00 │  888.00 │  892.00 │
│  A#5/Bb5  │  915.38 │  919.61 │  923.85 │  928.09 │  932.33 │  936.57 │  940.80 │  945.04 │
│ B5        │  969.81 │  974.30 │  978.79 │  983.28 │  987.77 │  992.26 │  996.75 │ 1001.24 │
│ C6        │ 1027.47 │ 1032.23 │ 1036.99 │ 1041.74 │ 1046.50 │ 1051.26 │ 1056.02 │ 1060.77 │
│  C#6/Db6  │ 1088.57 │ 1093.61 │ 1098.65 │ 1103.69 │ 1108.73 │ 1113.77 │ 1118.81 │ 1123.85 │
│ D6        │ 1153.30 │ 1158.64 │ 1163.98 │ 1169.32 │ 1174.66 │ 1180.00 │ 1185.34 │ 1190.68 │
│  D#6/Eb6  │ 1221.88 │ 1227.54 │ 1233.19 │ 1238.85 │ 1244.51 │ 1250.16 │ 1255.82 │ 1261.48 │
│ E6        │ 1294.54 │ 1300.53 │ 1306.52 │ 1312.52 │ 1318.51 │ 1324.50 │ 1330.50 │ 1336.49 │
│ F6        │ 1371.51 │ 1377.86 │ 1384.21 │ 1390.56 │ 1396.91 │ 1403.26 │ 1409.61 │ 1415.96 │
│  F#6/Gb6  │ 1453.07 │ 1459.80 │ 1466.52 │ 1473.25 │ 1479.98 │ 1486.70 │ 1493.43 │ 1500.16 │
│ G6        │ 1539.47 │ 1546.60 │ 1553.73 │ 1560.85 │ 1567.98 │ 1575.11 │ 1582.24 │ 1589.36 │
│  G#6/Ab6  │ 1631.01 │ 1638.57 │ 1646.12 │ 1653.67 │ 1661.22 │ 1668.77 │ 1676.32 │ 1683.87 │
│ A6        │ 1728.00 │ 1736.00 │ 1744.00 │ 1752.00 │ 1760.00 │ 1768.00 │ 1776.00 │ 1784.00 │
│  A#6/Bb6  │ 1830.75 │ 1839.23 │ 1847.70 │ 1856.18 │ 1864.66 │ 1873.13 │ 1881.61 │ 1890.08 │
│ B6        │ 1939.61 │ 1948.59 │ 1957.57 │ 1966.55 │ 1975.53 │ 1984.51 │ 1993.49 │ 2002.47 │
│ C7        │ 2054.95 │ 2064.46 │ 2073.98 │ 2083.49 │ 2093.00 │ 2102.52 │ 2112.03 │ 2121.54 │
│  C#7/Db7  │ 2177.14 │ 2187.22 │ 2197.30 │ 2207.38 │ 2217.46 │ 2227.54 │ 2237.62 │ 2247.70 │
│ D7        │ 2306.60 │ 2317.28 │ 2327.96 │ 2338.64 │ 2349.32 │ 2360.00 │ 2370.67 │ 2381.35 │
│  D#7/Eb7  │ 2443.76 │ 2455.07 │ 2466.39 │ 2477.70 │ 2489.02 │ 2500.33 │ 2511.64 │ 2522.96 │
│ E7        │ 2589.07 │ 2601.06 │ 2613.05 │ 2625.03 │ 2637.02 │ 2649.01 │ 2660.99 │ 2672.98 │
│ F7        │ 2743.03 │ 2755.73 │ 2768.43 │ 2781.13 │ 2793.83 │ 2806.52 │ 2819.22 │ 2831.92 │
│  F#7/Gb7  │ 2906.14 │ 2919.59 │ 2933.05 │ 2946.50 │ 2959.96 │ 2973.41 │ 2986.86 │ 3000.32 │
│ G7        │ 3078.95 │ 3093.20 │ 3107.45 │ 3121.71 │ 3135.96 │ 3150.22 │ 3164.47 │ 3178.73 │
│  G#7/Ab7  │ 3262.03 │ 3277.13 │ 3292.23 │ 3307.34 │ 3322.44 │ 3337.54 │ 3352.64 │ 3367.74 │
│ A7        │ 3456.00 │ 3472.00 │ 3488.00 │ 3504.00 │ 3520.00 │ 3536.00 │ 3552.00 │ 3568.00 │
│  A#7/Bb7  │ 3661.50 │ 3678.46 │ 3695.41 │ 3712.36 │ 3729.31 │ 3746.26 │ 3763.21 │ 3780.16 │
│ B7        │ 3879.23 │ 3897.19 │ 3915.15 │ 3933.11 │ 3951.07 │ 3969.03 │ 3986.99 │ 4004.95 │
│ C8        │ 4109.90 │ 4128.93 │ 4147.95 │ 4166.98 │ 4186.01 │ 4205.03 │ 4224.06 │ 4243.09 │
│  C#8/Db8  │ 4354.29 │ 4374.44 │ 4394.60 │ 4414.76 │ 4434.92 │ 4455.08 │ 4475.24 │ 4495.40 │
│ D8        │ 4613.21 │ 4634.56 │ 4655.92 │ 4677.28 │ 4698.63 │ 4719.99 │ 4741.35 │ 4762.71 │
│  D#8/Eb8  │ 4887.52 │ 4910.15 │ 4932.78 │ 4955.40 │ 4978.03 │ 5000.66 │ 5023.29 │ 5045.91 │
│ E8        │ 5178.15 │ 5202.12 │ 5226.09 │ 5250.07 │ 5274.04 │ 5298.01 │ 5321.99 │ 5345.96 │
│ F8        │ 5486.06 │ 5511.46 │ 5536.85 │ 5562.25 │ 5587.65 │ 5613.05 │ 5638.45 │ 5663.85 │
│  F#8/Gb8  │ 5812.28 │ 5839.18 │ 5866.09 │ 5893.00 │ 5919.91 │ 5946.82 │ 5973.73 │ 6000.64 │
│ G8        │ 6157.89 │ 6186.40 │ 6214.91 │ 6243.42 │ 6271.93 │ 6300.44 │ 6328.94 │ 6357.45 │
│  G#8/Ab8  │ 6524.06 │ 6554.26 │ 6584.47 │ 6614.67 │ 6644.88 │ 6675.08 │ 6705.28 │ 6735.49 │
│ A8        │ 6912.00 │ 6944.00 │ 6976.00 │ 7008.00 │ 7040.00 │ 7072.00 │ 7104.00 │ 7136.00 │
│  A#8/Bb8  │ 7323.01 │ 7356.91 │ 7390.81 │ 7424.72 │ 7458.62 │ 7492.52 │ 7526.43 │ 7560.33 │
│ B8        │ 7758.46 │ 7794.38 │ 7830.30 │ 7866.21 │ 7902.13 │ 7938.05 │ 7973.97 │ 8009.89 │
└───────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Source: http://pages.mtu.edu/~suits/notefreq446.html

(table above was made with excel and https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: What software do you use for spectrum analysis? Is there an easy way of figuring this out?

Comment: Any spectrum analysis software will do, or even a tuner app on your phone.

Comment: Oh, and as far as live music goes, all bets are off - unless there is an instrument (such as a keyboard) with fixed tuning or the band tunes between songs, things can drift quite a bit during a gig.

Comment: @Sebastian I'm not sure you can find anything OOTB that can do this in an automated way for you. You need to code some dedicated signal processing logic for that. If you just want to do a manual analysis you can use a spectogram (found in most audio editors)

Comment: I will look into Signal Processing logic, and spectograms. I've never heard of them.

Comment: @Sebastian If you can use VSTs, there is a free spectrum analyzer VST called SPAN that works very, very well.  I use it all the time when making music.